# How to give a PictureBox Control a Bullet or Projectile-like trayectory when a specific key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

Im a beginner with C# I'm doing some School project using a Windows Form App, It's a simple game but I ran into some issues, I want to give a picture box control a bullet-like trajectory when the [Space] key is pressed but haven't been able to do it yet. I was instructed to do this only using Threads and NO timers.

Also I want this picture box to 'spawn' and start moving from another picture box named 'SpaceShip' but i don't know how i could do that

Of course, advice and suggestions are very welcome even if it means changing entire parts of my awful code

I tried using picturebox.Left = picturebox.Left +5; but I guess i'm doing something wrong

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                        {
                            if(pbEnergy.Value <= 0)
                            {
                                pbEnergy.Value = 0;
                                System.Media.SoundPlayer SFX = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\SFX\nolaser.wav");
                                SFX.Play();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.Media.SoundPlayer SFX = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\SFX\laser.wav");
                                SFX.Play();
                                pbEnergy.Value -= 10;
                                ThreadStart Delegate = new ThreadStart(phys);
                                Thread MovTh = new Thread(Delegate);
                                MovTh.Start();
                            }
                        }

     public void phys()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    Progress(i);
                    if (i == 60) //stop when value is reached
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
                    }
                }
            }

            delegate void Delegate(int n);

            private void Progress(int num)
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Delegate d = new Delegate(Progress);
                    object[] Parameters = new object[] { num };
                    this.Invoke(d, Parameters);
                }
                else
                {
                    picprj.Visible = true;
                    picprj.Left = picprj.Left + 5;
                }
```

I expected the picture box to travel and then disappear but it finishes its trajectory and stays visible, I would appreciate some advice on this or even a better way to do it.

Comment: `I expected the picture box to travel and then disappear but it finishes its trajectory and stays visible` I don't see any code that calls `picprj.Visible = false;`  WinForms isn't a great gaming platform.

Comment: I know right? But I'm stuck with it, my professor only wanted this project in Windows Form Apps The "picprj.Visible = false;" is in the Form_Load Event sorry if i caused confusion

Comment: Well, ok, it's not visible when the form loads, but then you show it.  It won't ever go back to visible = false unless you specify that.